# ヘルプページ「良い質問をするには？」からのリンク先が不適当

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

日本語版ヘルプページの「[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)」の最下部に追加情報としていくつかリンクがありますが、「質問方法」のリンク先が「良い質問をするには？」の[原文(英語版)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)へのリンクとなっています。

ほぼ同じ内容にリンクしても有用性は薄い気がしますし、意図してリンクするにしてもリンクテキストが日本語で「質問方法」なのは不親切かなと。どちらにしても現状のリンクは中途半端な気がするので、思い切って削除するか、別のリンクに置き換えた方がよいかと思いました。

Comment: +1: 削除で良いと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

原文（英語版）へのリンクは削除いたしました。m_ _m。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]